# Styling <select> dropdowns with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I am new to JavaScript, HTML and CSS, although not to programming.

I wanted to style 'select' dropdowns, so I wrote this:

What noob mistakes am I making? Is this a good or evil use of JS?

```
<head>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--
<link href="./font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<style>
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.control { display: none; }
.dropdown > dl { margin: 4px; font-family: sans-serif; }
.dropdown > dl > dt { display:inline-block; width: auto; }
.dropdown .value { display: none; }
.dropdown > dl > dd { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 27px; display: none; }

.dropdown > dl { display:inline-block; width: auto; position: relative; cursor: pointer; }
.dropdown > dl > dt { border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #eee; color: black; padding: 3px 6px; font-weight: bold; }
.dropdown > dl > dd { border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: white; margin:0;}
.dropdown > dl > dd > ul { padding:0; margin:0 }
.dropdown > dl > dd > ul > li { list-style: none; padding:5px 10px; padding-left: 28px; }
.dropdown > dl > dt:hover,
.dropdown > dl > dd > ul > li:hover { background-color: #333; color: white; }
.dropdown > dl > dd > ul > li { display: none; }
.dropdown li.selected:before { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; content: '\f00c'; margin: 0 5px 0 -22px; font-weight: normal; }
.dropdown li.selected { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
-->

<script>
    function Dropdown(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.$root = $('#dropdown').clone().removeAttr('id').show();
        this.$root.children('dl').css('z-index', Dropdown.zindex.next());
        Controls.registerControl(this);

        this.$selected = this.$root.find('dt');
        this.$selectedContents = {
            $text: this.$selected.children('span.text'), 
            $value: this.$selected.children('span.value') };
        this.$popup = this.$root.find('dd');
        this.$options = this.$popup.children('ul');
        this.$option = this.$options.children('li');
        this.$optionContents = { 
            $text: this.$option.children('span.text'), 
            $value: this.$option.children('span.value') };

        var that = this;
        this.$selected.click(function(event) {
            if (!that.$popup.is(':visible')) {
                Controls.blurAll();
            }
            that.$popup.toggle();
        });
        this.$options.click(function(event) {
            that._selectOption($(event.target).is('li') ? $(event.target) : $(event.target).parent('li'));
            that.$popup.hide();
        });
    }
    Dropdown.prototype = {
        constructor: Dropdown,

        _makeOption: function(text, value) {
            this.$optionContents.$text.text(text);
            this.$optionContents.$value.text(value);
            return this.$option.clone();
        },

        setOptions: function(optionsMap) {
            for (var value in optionsMap) {
                var text = optionsMap[value];
                this._makeOption(text, value).appendTo(this.$options).show();
            }
            return this;
        },

        _selectOption: function($option) {
            var text = $option.children('span.text').text();
            var value = $option.children('span.value').text();

            this.$selectedContents.$text.text(text);
            this.$selectedContents.$value.text(value);

            this.$options.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $option.addClass('selected');

            this.$root.closest('form').find('[name="'+this.name+'"]').val(value);
        },

        selectOption: function(value) {
            var that = this;
            this.$options.find('li').each(function (idx, li) {
                if ($(li).find('span.value').text() == value) {
                    that._selectOption($(li));
                }
            });
            return this;
        },

        blur: function() {
            this.$popup.hide();
        }
    };
    Dropdown.replaceSelect = function($select) {
        var options = {};
        $select.children('option').each(function (idx, el) {
            options[$(el).val()] = $(el).text();
        });
        $select.hide().before(
            new Dropdown($select.prop('name'))
                .setOptions(options)
                .selectOption($select.children('option:selected').val())
                .$root);
    };
    Dropdown.replaceSelectByName = function(name) {
        Dropdown.replaceSelect($('select[name="' + name + '"]'));
    };
    Dropdown.replaceAllSelects = function() {
        $('select').each(function (idx, el) {
            Dropdown.replaceSelect($(el));
        });
    };
    Dropdown.zindex = {
        _idx: 100,
        next: function() { return this._idx--; }
    };

    Controls = {
        _controls: [],
        registerControl: function (control) {
            this._controls.push(control);
        },
        blurAll: function () {
            $.each(this._controls, function (idx, control) {
                control.blur();
            });
        }
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/cgi-bin/mycgi.pl">
<p>Naci en el mes de <select name="month">
    <option selected value=1>enero</option>
    <option value=2>febrero</option>
    <option value=3>marzo</option>
    <option value=4>avril</option>
    <option value=5>mayo</option>
    <option value=6>junio</option>
    <option value=7>julio</option>
    <option value=8>agosto</option>
    <option value=9>septiembre</option>
    <option value=10>octubre</option>
    <option value=11>noviembre</option>
    <option value=12>diciembre</option></select></p>
<p>Me gusta las <select name="fruit">
    <option value=1>manzanas</option>
    <option selected value=2>peras</option>
    <option value=3>naranjas</option></select></p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<span class="control dropdown" id="dropdown">
<dl>
    <dt><span class="text"></span><span class="value"></span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></dt>
    <dd><ul>
        <li><span class="text"></span><span class="value"></span></li>
    </ul></dd>
</dl>
</span>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropdown.replaceAllSelects();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do I conclude that no-one knows if this is good or evil, or that it was so evil (or good) that it left everyone speechless?

Comment: Be assured that we are quick to point out evil. However, if it is difficult to find constuctive criticism (i.e. what is posted is too good or too complex/specific) that can definitely silence the masses.

Comment: For this kind of question, you should use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I use [jQuery-selectbox plugin](https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox) to style `select` dropdowns, you may have a look at this code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and links. All useful and taken on board.

Answer (score 2):

## Tip for your code:

- Use `$name` for var names that represent a jQuery selection, nor for a member (it is the convention).
- Since you use jQuery, consider writing a plugin extending `jQuery.fn` instead of prototyping

Comment: You couldn't have his code working? Weird. http://jsfiddle.net/sciencepharaoh/JwXPc/

Comment: How did you get it to work @DanielCook ???

Comment: @Malachi I put it in JSFiddle? Is it not working? I'm confused. It looks like it works to me. Though my linked fiddle removed some of the options but it worked with them in there as well. Actually, I did add 1 unnecessary semi-colon to make JSHint happy...

Comment: @DanielCook, I tried to take the code from the original question post, and it was a plain drop down menu.  I am probably making noob mistakes myself

Comment: @Sinsedrix, the `tip for your code` section is the only section that is actually a review in my opinion

Comment: @Malachi, should I remove the rest of recommandations to have an upvote instead of a downvote?

Comment: the JSFiddle thing is a comment, the fact that you use a plugin is also a comment, your problem rendering the UTF-8 is sort of an off topic comment, and the OP has that link in their code. So I would say yes

Comment: @sinsedrix - I _have_ used $name for variable names that represent a jQuery selection, check again. It's just that I store a number of them in member variables. Eg aDropdown.name is a string while aDropdown.$options references the <ul> of options.

Comment: @Malachi yes the only thing was the reference to fontawesome css for the tick and down-caret symbols, which wants to go in the External Resources section on the left instead of in a <link> tag in the css section http://jsfiddle.net/JwXPc/2/ :)

Comment: @user2886246 `this.$xxx` are members not **variables** that represent a jQuery selection.